# How to copy Rails app with existing git repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, repository, bitbucket

I want to copy and paste my Rails app, only with different name. Here is my problem.

When I go into my new rails app folder its on master branch, but I can't push anything from there. It belongs to my first(old) app. I should remove git from new app and make entirely new repository, or even better copy and paste repository from old app and change its name, so I could push new app to new repository and old app to old repository.

is there away to do this.

Answer (score 0):

look in the `.git/config` for

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@bitbucket.org:some_path.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and change that